# TFS Iteration Board Not Showing for Team

Tags: backlog

I have a TFS project setup with multiple teams.  One of the team's backlog has disappeared even though it appears that everything is setup correctly.  Let me detail it out:

I have the iterations setup for the team with the correct ones selected:
[image: Iteration Setup]

As you can see, the current sprint is Sprint 5.  I have stories in this sprint as can be seen below:

[image: Stories]

But when I view my backlog, nothing shows.  What else should I check?

[image]

Comment: Area path of these work items and of the team?

Comment: I didn't think the area paths mattered for the sprint board, but I'll check when I get back to my desk.

Comment: It does as teams are bound to areas as well as sprints

Comment: Then that's likely the problem.  I'll check as soon as I can.  Thanks.

Comment: That was it - if you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is shown on the Sprint/Iteration Board is governed by 2 things:

1. The Iteration Path's which are enabled for the team
2. The Area paths that are enabled for the team

If the template has been customized there is a third option, which not many people know about:

3. Instead of Area path a custom field can be specified. This is the so-called Team-Field.